# set applicationIdSuffix depending on productFlavor

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

We have 2 `productFlavors` (*testServer, liveServer*) and 2 build types (*debug, release).*

Due to existing API keys, I have to append package names based on buildType + productFlavor.

For example something like:

```
buildTypes {
  debug {
   applicationIdSuffix '.dbg' + (testServer ? '.test' : '.live')
  }

  release {
   applicationidSuffix '' + (testServer ? '.test')
  }  
}
```

is this possible? how?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
productFlavors {
    testServer {
        applicationId = "com.example.my.pkg.test"
    }
    liveServer {
        applicationId = "com.example.my.pkg.live"
    }
}

buildTypes {
    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
    }
}
```

For more information, take a look at the [Android documentation](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/applicationid-vs-packagename) regarding application ids.