# Android - The package conflicts with an existing package by the same name

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I´ve this default config on Gradle.

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.my.application"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 190011
    versionName "2.2.1"
}
```

And those flavors

```
productFlavors {
    dev {
        applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
        versionCode 333333
        buildConfigField "String", "ANVIL_BASE_URL", "DEBUG_URL"
        resValue "string", "app_name", "app name dev"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.releasesign
    }
    prod {
        buildConfigField "String", "ANVIL_BASE_URL", "PROD_URL"
        resValue "string", "app_name", "app name"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.releasesign
    }
}
```

I´ve got the app released on the Play Store with the default application id "com.my.application" but when I´ve the Play Store version installed and want to install the "dev" flavored application it pop a message that says this:

```
app name dev 
App not installed
The package conflicts with an existing package by the same name
```

Am I doing something wrong? I´ve tried changing the buildCode for dev but that didn't work either.

Any guess?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, while trying to install a modified version of the app through command line I found the following error:

```
adb install ~/Desktop/app-dev-release.apk
Failed to install /Users/axier/Desktop/app-dev-release.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_DUPLICATE_PERMISSION: Package com.my.application.dev attempting to redeclare permission com.my.application.permission.C2D_MESSAGE already owned by com.my.application]
```

So I´ve modified my AndroidManifest.xml file like this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

Pretty poor error description for this one. Hope the solution works for someone like me in the future.

Thanks anyway.

Comment: Bless you so much, this is a nasty pitfall. Trying to get a fork of an app run side by side with the original app, this will be the common issue. Obviously, I don't want to change any namespaces, so I just specified a new `applicationId`, but the old one was hardcoded everywhere. You are a life saver.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at [the gradle documentation (ApplicationId versus PackageName)](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/applicationid-vs-packagename). Also, have you really released the version on the play store with the package name "com.my.application"? My suggestion to your problem would be to put the applicationId into the productFlavors. Also take a look at [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29297934/set-applicationidsuffix-depending-on-productflavor), which basically answers your question as well.

Answer (score 0):

You've installed an application on your phone with same package name.Reinstall int before you install this one.

Comment: That´s not like that, before the first crash I had both apps installed together on my device and when executing alias packages='adb shell '"'"'pm list packages -f'"'"' | sed -e '"'"'s/.*=//'"'"' | sort' they showed different packages.