# Creating different package names with build variants productFlavors

Tags: java, android, gradle

I am creating 2 different apps with gradle productFlavors and now I want to create apps with different package names according to the flavors, how can I create different packages with flavors.

I use this to create flavors and works great I create 2 apps;

```
    productFlavors{
        ABC{

        }
        EFG{

        }
    }
    configurations {
        ABC
        EFG
    }
```

On the app side I am controlling the flavors like this;

```
        if (BuildConfig.FLAVOR.equals("ABC")) {
            Log.v("APP", "ABC");
        }
        if(BuildConfig.FLAVOR.equals("EFG")) {
            Log.v("APP", "EFG");
        }
```

My package name is;

```
package com.example.myapp
```

With build types I want to create different apps with different build types with these flavors, there will be 2 app packages and they have to still use build variants.
My app names will be "prs" and "xyz" and control them in the app side with something like this;

```
    if (BuildConfig.FLAVOR.equals("ABC") && Package.Name.equals(prs)) {
        Log.v("APP prs", "ABC");
    }
    if(BuildConfig.FLAVOR.equals("EFG") && Package.Name.equals(prs)) {
        Log.v("APP prs", "EFG");
    }
    if (BuildConfig.FLAVOR.equals("ABC") && Package.Name.equals(xyz)) {
        Log.v("APP xyz", "ABC");
    }
    if(BuildConfig.FLAVOR.equals("EFG") && Package.Name.equals(xyz)) {
        Log.v("APP xyz", "EFG");
    }
```

There will be four APK's generated like this;

```
com.example.prs - ABC Flavor
com.example.prs - EFG Flavor

com.example.xyz - ABC Flavor
com.example.xyz - EFG Flavor
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [set applicationIdSuffix depending on productFlavor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29297934/set-applicationidsuffix-depending-on-productflavor)

Comment: Not much, can not control the package variants with the flavors @RickyMo

Comment: @TheEngineeeeeeer What you mean 'can not control the package variants'? Can you describe your use case? If you could give an example, that would be great.

Comment: I mean, I want to control the packages with variants which I added at the last section. 2 Packages and each package has 2 flavors and I need to change the packages with 
if (BuildConfig.FLAVOR.equals("ABC") && Package.Name.equals(prs)) { ...